# Fullcalendar - Limit days to a single all day event in month view

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Is it possible to limit a day to a single all day event in month view?  This ideally would handle individual date selections, as well as date ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most certainly a better way to do this, but this is what I was able to come up with for the time being.  I'd like to be able to accomplish this without having to loop all of the events.

```
select: function (newEvent_start, newEvent_end, allDay) {
                var okToAdd = true;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
                    if ( (newEvent_start >= event.start && newEvent_end <= event.end) || // between
                         (newEvent_start <= event.start && newEvent_end >= event.start) || // starts before, ends during
                         (newEvent_start >= event.start && newEvent_start <= event.end && newEvent_end >= event.end)  // starts during, ends after
                       )
                        okToAdd = false;
                });

                if (okToAdd) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: 'Title goes here',
                        start: newEvent_start,
                        end: newEvent_end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true 
                );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
```